# How does this assembly function return a value?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I have made a function in C which is pretty straightforward, it uses `strlen()` from `<string.h>` to return the length of a `char*` variable:

```
int length(char *str) {

    return strlen(str);
}
```

Here is the corresponding x86_64 assembly from `objdump -M intel -d a.out`:

```
00000000000011a8 <length>:
    11a8:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11ac:   55                      push   rbp
    11ad:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
    11b0:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10
    11b4:   48 89 7d f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdi
    11b8:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
    11bc:   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax
    11bf:   e8 ac fe ff ff          call   1070 <strlen@plt>
    11c4:   c9                      leave  
    11c5:   c3                      ret
```

Here is my current understanding of the code (please correct me if anything seems wrong):

```
00000000000011a8 <length>:
    11a8:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    11ac:   55                      push   rbp  // stack setup, old rbp of previous frame pushed
    11ad:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp // rbp and rsp point to same place
    11b0:   48 83 ec 10             sub    rsp,0x10 // space is made for arguments
    11b4:   48 89 7d f8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdi // rdi stores argument and is moved into the space made on the line 11b0
    11b8:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] // value at memory address rbp-0x8 aka argument is stored in rax
    11bc:   48 89 c7                mov    rdi,rax // move the value into rdi for function call
    11bf:   e8 ac fe ff ff          call   1070 <strlen@plt> // strlen() is called
    11c4:   c9                      leave  // stack clear up
    11c5:   c3                      ret // return address popped and control flow resumes
```

If anything above is incorrect please correct me, secondly how does `call   1070 <strlen@plt>` return a value? because the strlen() function returns the length of a string and i would have thought that something would have been moved into the `rax` register (which i believe is commonly used for return values). But nothing is moved into `rax` and it does not show a value returned in the assembly.

Lastly here is the code at address 1070 (from call   1070 strlen@plt)

```
0000000000001070 <strlen@plt>:
    1070:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
    1074:   f2 ff 25 45 2f 00 00    bnd jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2f45]        # 3fc0 <strlen@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    107b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Comment: Put simply, the calling convention is that `rax` contains the return value of a C function. So `call   1070 <strlen@plt>` returns a value in `rax` (the length of the string), which is then left intact to be returned to the caller of `length`. The `length` function doesn't need to do anything with `rax` in this case. See [x64 Calling Conventionn - Return Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#return-values) for more details.

Comment: What did you see in RAX when you single-stepped it with a debugger?  (Using `nexti` to step over the strlen call).  Can you think how it would have gotten there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how does call   1070 strlen@plt return a value?

The `strlen` puts its result into `rax` register, which conveniently is also where your `length()` function should put *its* return value.

Under optimization your `length()` could be compiled into a single instruction: `jmp strlen` -- the parameter is already in `rdi`, and the return value will be in `rax`.

P.S.

> Lastly here is the code at address 1070

That isn't the actual code of `strlen`. This is a "PLT jump stub". To understand what that is, you could read [this blog post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries).

Also, from that small address, you can see this is a PIE executable: those are just offsets from the image base address; the runtime address will be something like `0x55...`